# Random not working with list for various reasons

Tags: python, pygame

I want to select a random alien sprite out of the imported sprites (`ALIEN1`, `ALIEN2`, `ALIEN3`) to show up as the randomly generated alien.

[Here is the gihub](https://github.com/GreenishUwU/PySpaceInvadersHelp)

```py
# load aliens #
ALIEN1 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sprites","alien1_frame1.png"))
ALIEN2 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sprites","alien2_frame1.png"))
ALIEN3 = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("sprites","alien3_frame1.png"))
```

```py
class Enemy(Ship):
    ALIEN_CHOICE = [ALIEN1, ALIEN2, ALIEN3]
    def __init__(self, x, y, color, health=100):
        super().__init__(x,y, health)
        self.ship_img = self.ALIEN_CHOICE[color]
        # mask #
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)

    def move(self, vel): # movement variables for enemies
        self.y += vel
```

```py
enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(Enemy.ALIEN_CHOICE))
```

Comment: Could you explain what not working and post also a piece of the code here ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clearly state your problem and include the minimum code required to reproduce your problem. See the [ask] page for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a random element from a list, then I recommend to use `random.choice()` ([`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)):

```py
import random
```

```py
alien_list = [ALIEN1, ALIEN2, ALIEN3]
random_alien = random.choice(alien_list)
```

---

The argument to the constructor of  `Enemy` is the image of the alien ship:

```py
class Enemy(Ship):
    ALIEN_CHOICE = [ALIEN1, ALIEN2, ALIEN3]
    def __init__(self, x, y, ship_img, health=100):
        super().__init__(x,y, health)
        self.ship_img = ship_img 
        # mask #
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
```

```py
enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500, -100), random.choice(Enemy.ALIEN_CHOICE))
```

---

Alternatively you can skip the argument completely (that's up to you):

```py
class Enemy(Ship):
    ALIEN_CHOICE = [ALIEN1, ALIEN2, ALIEN3]
    def __init__(self, x, y, health=100):
        super().__init__(x,y, health)
        self.ship_img = random.choice(Enemy.ALIEN_CHOICE) 
        # mask #
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.ship_img)
```

```py
enemy = Enemy(random.randrange(50, WIDTH-100), random.randrange(-1500, -100))
```

Comment: I gave that a go before, I don't think it worked for one reason or another, however I will give it a go when I get the chance. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use random like so. Create a random number generator, create a list of all of your aliens, then index the list with random.

```
import random
aliens = ['alien1', 'alien2', 'alien3']

for r in range(10):
    print(aliens[random.randint(0,2)])



alien3
alien2
alien1
alien1
alien1
alien2
alien3
alien1
alien1
alien2

[Program finished]
```

Comment: I'll give something like that a go when I get the chance :)